# Google Cloud authentication with JSON keyfile using cURL

Tags: curl, oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, gcloud

I have a JSON key file for Google Cloud in the form of:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "###",
  "private_key_id": "###",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n
  ########################################
  \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "###@###.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "###",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/###.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I would like to get an `access_token` while using regular curl commands instead of the [GCP Console](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/common/auth) or installing the [gcloud tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/).

I would expect something like:

```sh
curl \
--request POST \
--data-binary "@path/to/key.json" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Comment: See here:
https://github.com/google/oauth2l

Comment: I'm also trying to do this, because I'm using gsutil in my CI Docker images and it takes ~100MB to install everything (including Python.) It would be really nice if I could interact with GCS from a simple bash script instead of installing all these heavy dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## curl is not enough

I don't think you're going to be able to do it with just `curl`, because I believe it requires JWT authentication - reading between the lines in the docs and the error messages I've gotten myself.

- https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/getting-started#api

## oauth2l: a lightweight-ish approach

They have [`oauth2l`](https://github.com/google/oauth2l), which can generate the JWT from the `service_account.json` JWK (though it should also work with the one you have which uses a PEM or CRT instead).

Unfortunately, they don't have a direct download link, but it's not *too* hard to get:

Try this:

Install Go:

- See https://webinstall.dev/golang (easy) or https://golang.org/dl (a good read)

Then install `oauth2l`:

```bash
go install github.com/google/oauth2l@latest
```

Then generate a JWT API Token:

```
oauth2l fetch --jwt --json ./service_account.json https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

## Back to curl

Then use `curl` to fetch the API you want:

```
token=$(oauth2l fetch --jwt --json ./service_account.json https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform)

curl -X POST https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/<project>/managedZones \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

It's not ideal, but I think that'll get you what you need with minimal abstraction.

## Less abstraction still

I'll try to post back when I get this figured out. It's going to require some sort of tool, but I think it can be even lighter-weight than `oauth2l`.

Comment: On MacOSX, you can use "brew install oauth2l" without installing go.

Answer (score 1):

Precompiled oauth2l binaries are available for download from [oauth2l GitHub page](https://github.com/google/oauth2l):

[macos](https://storage.googleapis.com/oauth2l/latest/darwin_amd64.tgz) [Linux](https://storage.googleapis.com/oauth2l/latest/linux_amd64.tgz) [Windows](https://storage.googleapis.com/oauth2l/latest/windows_amd64.tgz)